# my class in c++ crashes in the constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

I have this constructor code and it crashes for a reason I can't find. I'll be glad if someone finds the error. Thank you!

```
Person::Person(int id[9], string name, int age)
{
    cout << "Constractor" << endl << endl;
    _id = new int(9);
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        this->_id[i] = id[i];
    }
    this->_name = name;
    this->_age = age;
}
```

Comment: I would use std::array<int, 9> for representing the person's id and do the following in the constructor:
Person::Person(const std::array<int, 9>& id,...) : _id(id) {...}
Assuming your compiler supports C++11.

Comment: None of those `this->`s is needed. The compiler knows that it's dealing with members.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `_id = new int[9];` and not `_id = new int(9);` (Which just creates one int on the heap with 9 as the initial value).

Also, make sure you free the allocated space properly in the destructor (Use delete[]).

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
_id = new int(9);
```

does not give an array of 9 int. Try

```
_id = new int[9];
```

Answer (score 1):

**Side Note**

The signature of:

```
void test(int id[9]){}
void test(int id[]){}
```

is the same as

```
void test(int* id){}
```

To avoid passing a pointer of insufficient length you may pass an array by reference:

```
void test(int (&id)[9]){}

int main() {
    int id[9] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
    test(id);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Never seen such a syntax. Will it fail for an array of a different size?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Yes (smaller or greater)

Answer (score 0):

That's because you declared `_id` as a `int` and not as a `int []`. Try to type `_id = new int [9];`
As your code says, everytime you call that constructor, in the heap memory is created a new int that is not an array (that's because the syntax `int a(9);` is the same as `int a = 9;`) and it obviously crashes because your trying to use that variable as an array in the `for` cycle

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in `_id = new int(9);`, which just creates an integer whose value is 9.
You should use `_id = new int[9];`